# Heatmaps in ggplot using multiple variables (formatted as individual columns)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, heatmap

I'm looking to make a Heatmap from some protein signature data in ggplot, but haven't been able to figure out how to wrangle the dataframe so I can visualize properly. Here is an example of the data format:

```
CellLine, Protein1, Protein2, Protein3, Protein 4
Cancer1, 0.22, 1.15, 0.68, 0.44
Cancer2, 0.95, 1.54, 0.55, 0.02
Cancer3, 1.20, 0.85, 0.99, 0.89
```

Ideally, I'd like to show the cell line on the y-axis and the proteins on the x-axis, with the respective expression values filling in the color scale. Please let me know if you have any suggestions, would greatly appreciate the help!

CtrlsMatrixed <- DF from above

```
CtrlsMatrixed <- ControlsDF %>% pivot_longer(cols = 3:45, cols_vary = "fastest", names_to =   "GeneSignature")
```

Code came back with error in pivot_longer()--> couldn't combine `CellLine` <character> and Protein1 <double>

***** EDIT for Allan:

```
structure(list(`PI3K-p110-a-R-C` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `PI3K-p85-R-C` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `EGFR-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `EGFR_pY1173-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `FGF-basic-R-C` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `c-Kit-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `c-Met_pY1234_Y1235-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
), `PDK1-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `PDK1_pS241-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `PTEN-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Akt-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Akt1-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Akt1_pS473-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Akt2-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Akt2_pS474-R-C` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Akt_pS473-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Akt_pT308-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `FOXO3-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `FoxO3a_pS318_S321-R-C` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `PKCa-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `PKC-a-b-II_pT638_T641-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `TSC1-R-C` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `mTOR-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `mTOR_pS2448-R-C` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Rictor-R-C...28` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Rictor_pT1135-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Raptor-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `PRAS40_pT246-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `p70-S6K_pT389-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `S6_pS235_S236-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `S6_pS240_S244-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `4E-BP1-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `4E-BP1_pS65-R-V` = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `4E-BP1_pT37_T46-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    `eIF4E-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `eIF4E_pS209-R-V` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `p38-MAPK-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `p38-MAPK-_pT180_Y182-R-V` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `p44-42-MAPK-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    `MEK1_pS217_S221-R-V` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `p90RSK_pT573-R-C` = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), `Rictor-R-C...45` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    CellLines = c("Cancer A", "Cancer E", "Cancer C", "Cancer F", 
    "Cancer D", "Cancer B")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in ggplot quite easily with `geom_tile`

```r
library(tidyverse)

ControlsDF %>%
  pivot_longer(-CellLine, names_to = 'Protein', values_to = 'Expression') %>%
  ggplot(aes(Protein, CellLine, fill = Expression)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
ControlsDF <-  structure(list(CellLine = c("Cancer1", "Cancer2", "Cancer3"), 
               Protein1 = c(0.22, 0.95, 1.2), Protein2 = c(1.15, 1.54, 0.85
               ), Protein3 = c(0.68, 0.55, 0.99), Protein4 = c(0.44, 0.02, 
                0.89)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

---

**EDIT**

Using the data in the `dput` output above, we can use essentially the same code:

```r
ControlsDF %>%
  pivot_longer(-CellLines, names_to = 'Protein', values_to = 'Expression') %>%
  ggplot(aes(Protein, CellLines, fill = Expression)) +
  geom_tile(color = 'black') +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  coord_equal(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply Allan. I tried your code with my original data frame and received the following error

`Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`

It seems to be referring to the x-value for the visualization-- the CellLine equivalent. Do you think there is some reformatting to do here? i.e. transforming the 'Cell Line' variable? How would you go about handling this error

Comment: @Jeremybravo I can't say without seeing your actual data. Are you able to edit your question to include the output of `dput(ControlsDF)`?  I can only show how to work with the data you provide in your question. Alternatively a DropBox or Google Sheet  or Gist link would work.

Comment: Hey Allan, I added the output of the `dput()` function into the question. Thanks again for all your expertise.

Comment: @Jeremybravo that's great - thanks, but I don't get any error with essentially the same code using that data either - you will see the output I'm getting in my edit above.

Comment: I found some errors in the syntax I was using, but your code worked great! Thank you so much :)